# How to ClearInterval in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to clear an interval in my vuex store but it doesn't work.

In startCounter I check if my count is equal to 100 to clear the interval in stopCounter with

```
clearInterval(this.myCounterInterval);
```

Here is my code, thank you.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import videos from "@/models/videos";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
    totalTime: 20,
    myCounterInterval: 0,
    visible: false,
    show: false,
    videos: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => videos
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    visibleProgressBar (state) {
      state.visible = true;
    },
    invisibleProgressBar (state) {
      state.visible = false;
    },
    showModal (state) {
      state.show = true;
    },
    hideModal (state) {
      state.show = false;
    },
    countDown (state) {
      if(state.totalTime >= 1) {
        state.totalTime--;
        state.count += 5;
      } else {
        state.totalTime = 0;
        state.count = 0;
        return;
      }
    },
    setCounter (state, newCount) {
      state.count = newCount;
    },
    stopCounter (state) {
      clearInterval(this.myCounterInterval);
      state.count = 0;
    },
    setVideos (state) {
      state.videos;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    startCounter ({ state, commit }) {

      this.myCounterInterval = commit("setCounter", setInterval(() => {
        commit("countDown");

        if(state.count === 100) {
          commit("stopCounter");
        }
      }, 1000));
    },
    stopCounter ({ commit }) {
      commit("stopCounter");
    },
    showProgressBar ({ commit }) {
      commit("visibleProgressBar");
    },
    hideProgressBar ({ commit }) {
      commit("invisibleProgressBar");
    },
    showModal ({ commit }) {
      commit("showModal");
    },
    hideModal ({ commit }) {
      commit("hideModal");
    },
    getVideos ({ commit }) {
      commit("setVideos");
    }
  },
  modules: {}
});
```

Comment: In this instance did you just mistakenly use `clearInterval(this.myCounterInterval);` when you meant `clearInterval(state.myCounterInterval);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
stopCounter (state) {
    state.myCounterInterval = null
    ...
},
```

Set interval like this

**actions**

```
startCounter ({ state, commit }) {
      commit("setCounter")
}
```

**mutations**

```
setCounter (state) {
   state.count = 0;
   state.myCounterInterval = setInterval(() => {
      your logic
   }, 1000))
},
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't seem to work either, maybe it's the way I set the interval ?

Comment: I can't do my logic in mutations because I need to do commit("countDown"); in the setInterval

Comment: What`s the problem to do all mutations from countDown in interval?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this assignment:

```
this.myCounterInterval = commit("setCounter", setInterval(() => {
```

, and just commit:

```
commit("setCounter", setInterval(() => {
```

"setCounter" mutation assigns your counter to a state.count:

```
setCounter (state, newCount) {
  state.count = newCount;
}
```

, and then you can delete this interval:

```
stopCounter (state) {
  clearInterval(state.count);
}
```

This one works for me